# Can't get saveRow aftersavefunc or successFunc to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've got some code that, when switching which row is selected, it triggers a save of the previously selected row.

The row is being successfully saved without any problem, however the `successfunc` isn't being called at all - my `console.log` output never shows up, and the code in this function isn't being run. I also tried specifying the function as the `aftersavefunc`, but couldn't get that to work either.

Seems like a simple syntax problem, but I can't quite get it right. Am I not specifying this function properly?

As a side note, I realize that reloading the entire grid after a row save seems like overkill, but in the context of where this particular piece of code is, within the larger structure of my app, this snippet of code is a special case.

The full jqGrid code is:

```
var lastSelectedMainGridRowID = 0;
var lastSelectedSubGridRowID = 0;
var translationsFeed = "/update/translations/ajax/translations_feed.php";
var translationsEdit = "/update/translations/ajax/translations_edit.php";
var translationsSubGridFeed = "ajax/translations_subgrid_feed.php";
var translationsSubGridFeedEdit = "ajax/translations_subgrid_feed_edit.php";

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#translationsList").jqGrid({
    caption : "Translations",
    datatype : "xml",
    url : translationsFeed,
    editurl : translationsEdit,
    mtype : "get",
    pager : "#translationsPager",
    rowNum : 20,
    autowidth : true,
    sortname : "phrase",
    sortorder : "asc",
    viewrecords : true,
    multiselect : false,
    hidegrid : false,
    height : 300,
    altRows : true,
    rownumbers : true,
    toolbar : [false],
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        jQuery("#translationsList").setSelection (0, true);
    },
    colNames : ["phrase_id", "translation_id", "language_cd", "Phrase", "Translation", "Modified", "Created", "Active"],
    colModel : [
            { name : "phrase_id",                                   index : "phrase_id",            sortable : true,    search : false, editable: true, edittype : "text",      editrules: { edithidden: true },                                    hidden: true},
            { name : "translation_id",                          index : "translation_id", sortable : false, search : false, editable: true, edittype : "text",      editrules: { edithidden: true },                                    hidden: true},
            { name : "language_cd",                                 index : "language_cd",      sortable : true,    search : true,  editable: true, edittype : "text",      editrules: { edithidden: true, required : true }, hidden: true },
        { name : "Phrase",              width:200,  index : "phrase",               sortable : true,    search : true,  editable: true, edittype : "text",      editrules: { required: true } },
        { name : "Translation",         width:200,  index : "translation",      sortable : true,    search : true,  editable: true, edittype : "text",      editrules: { required: false } },
        { name : "Modified",            width:100,  index : "modify_dt",            sortable : true,    search : true },
        { name : "Created",             width:100,  index : "create_dt",            sortable : true,    search : true },
        { name : "Active",              width:20,       index : "active",               sortable : true,    search : true,  editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value:"Yes:No", checked: true} }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
            jQuery('#translationsList').jqGrid('saveRow', lastSelectedMainGridRowID);
            jQuery('#translationsList').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
            lastSelectedMainGridRowID = id;
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id;
        jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url: translationsSubGridFeed + "?phrase_id=" + row_id,
            editurl: translationsSubGridFeedEdit,
            datatype: "xml",
            colNames: ['phrase_id', 'translation_id', 'language_cd', 'Translations', 'Language', 'Active'],
            colModel: [
                            {name:"phrase_id",          index:"phrase_id",          sortable: false,    editable: true,     edittype : "text", editrules: { edithidden :true },                             hidden: true},
                            {name:"translation_id", index:"translation_id", sortable: false,    editable: true,     edittype : "text", editrules: { edithidden :true },                             hidden: true},
                            {name:"language_cd",        index:"language_cd",        sortable: false,    editable: true,     edittype : "text", editrules: { edithidden :true },                             hidden: true},                          
                    {name:"Translation",        index:"translation",        sortable: true,     editable: true,     edittype:"text",                                                                                                    width:589},
                {name:"Language",               index:"language_disp",  sortable: true,     editable: false,                                                                                                                                        width:250},
                {name:"Active",                 index:"active",                 sortable: true,     editable: true,     edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value:"Yes:No", checked: true}, width:80}
            ],
            height: "100%",
            rowNum:20,
            sortname: 'language_cd',
            sortorder: "asc",
            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('saveRow', lastSelectedSubGridRowID, function(response) {
                  console.log("Data: " + response.responseText);
                  return false;
                });
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastSelectedSubGridRowID = id;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Perhaps I don't need to use saveRow. In this case, what I'm doing is:

1. When you click on a row, it becomes editable
2. If you then click on a second row, the first row is saved (and no longer selected), and the new second row then becomes editable. Similar to saving a row "onBlur", so to speak.

Comment: could you include more full code which you use? Many opened questions could be very important. For example the `datatype` of the grid. It is also very important **in which context** you use `saveRow` because in the most cases one should use `editRow` instead.

Comment: Sure thing. Posted the full jqGrid code at the end there.

Comment: Small additional remark to your code. I recommend you to save (cache) `$("#translationsList")` in a variable and use the variable later. In the case the `$("#translationsList")` should not be calculated very time by jQuery. For example: `var $translationsList=$("#translationsList");   $translationsList.jqGrid({...})`. In the same way inside of `subGridRowExpanded` event handler you can save `jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id)` in another variable and use it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the place of code where `responseData` variable are defined. The code `responseData[0]` should throw an exception, so the `console.log("Data: " + responseData[0]);` will not display any data. The line of code should be probably fixed as

```
console.log("Server response: " + result.responseText);
```

**UPDATED**: Without having the data for the both grid and for example the subgrid corresponds the first row one can't debug the code. Reading is not so effective. If you posted the test data (two XML files) I could try to localize the problem.

An important error is that you only declare `subgrid_table_id` variable, but not assign a value for it. Typically one construct an unique id name `subgrid_table_id` based on the `subgrid_id`. For example

```
var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
```

instead of `var subgrid_table_id;` only.

Nevertheless some things I find a little suspected:

1. I don't understand why you return `return false;` from the `successfunc`. It means that you interpret the server response as an error and the normal actions on successful server response should be interrupted. I would recommend you additionally use `errorfunc` parameter of [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow). In my server code the server always return error HTML status code in case of the server error. So I never need use `successfunc` and use `aftersavefunc` and `errorfunc` only.
2. The subgrid has many column which already exist in the corresponding row of the parent grid. The potential problems here are not only spending of additional memory. You don't posted the grid data and so I don't know what values you use as rowids for grids. It is very important to have no id duplicates on the HTML page. So you should be careful in the subject. Why you need ? Probably you can just use `extraparam` parameter of [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) and [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) instead of the usage of `phrase_id`, `translation_id` and `language_cd` hidden columns having `editable: true, editrules: { edithidden :true }, hidden: true` properties?

Comment: Cool, I'll try this out later this afternoon. Thanks again, Oleg.

Comment: @normalocity: You are welcome! Don't forget to replace `if (result == 'reloadGrid') {` to `if (result.responseText === 'reloadGrid') {` additionally.

Comment: Hey, Oleg. I've updated the jqGrid code sample, and I'm still not getting any of the code inside of that successfunc to run. Am I still not specifying that function correctly? The rows are successfully saving to the DB, so I know the save itself is working, and I'm not seeing any errors in Firebug.

Comment: @normalocity: Before all small remark: you wrote in one place `lastSelectedSubGridRowID` variable in a wrong way: `lastSelectedSudGridRowID` (Su**d** instead of Su**b**). At the end of the code you don't copied additional `});`. I am starting to look at the example more exactly...

Comment: @normalocity: You are welcome! I updated my answer. If you will still have problems you should include in the code of your question two XML files: the server response from the main grid (with at least one row of data and the corresponding subgrid XML data). By the way why you use XML and not JSON? Working with JSON is more quickly and comfortable in jqGrid.

Comment: The next time you're in the States, or I'm in Germany, I'm buying you a pint. Thanks again - I'll take another look through this stuff.

Comment: I never did get the aftersavefunc to work. I found other ways to do what I needed to do, and I made the other caching/coding changes you suggested. In the end, everything is working the way I needed it to.

Comment: @normalocity: Look at [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing.htm) or [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingOnEnter.htm). Both use the `aftersavefunc`. You can place the breakpoint to any line inside of `aftersavefunc` and you will see that the function will be called.

Comment: I finally figured out where my issue was. I was defining an 'aftersavefunc', but I was only specifying one parameter for that function, where the documentation clearly states that the function gets TWO parameters: the resulting rowID, and the response from the server.